# How do i set the scope in the ask cli

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, alexa-skills-kit

I am new working with AWS services and i want to use cloudformation to generate an alexa skill. For this i need a LWA token that is generated via "ask util generate-lwa-token". I use the client ID and secret ID provided here.[page of the security profile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JnNvr.png)

When i enter the IDs a webpage open with this.[error page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/snGxa.png)

What i am missing? Where do i need to put the scope?

Answer (score 0):

After looking for more documentation when you use the command

"ask util generate-lwa-token" you need to use "--scope profile", that will send the scope required to login